# Получить запрос с api.ai

Tags: php, json, post, api, curl

Создаю бота на базе `api.ai` сервиса. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не знаю как получить данные запроса, который вводится пользователем. Например пользователь ввел "Бот, скажи мне что такое машина". Через вебхук он ссылается на мой удаленный сервер и как раз там я не могу словить эту фразу. Подскажите возможно ли как-то это реализовать средствами PHP. Обратный запрос я посылаю через `curl`.

json пример запроса боту :

```
{
  "id": "209c1797-eec7-44be-877a-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "timestamp": "2017-06-13T12:20:38.624Z",
  "lang": "ru",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "поле",
    "action": "input.unknown",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "ccf1151e-8851-40d2-9300-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "Default Fallback Intent"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Вот эта последняя фраза мне не ясна.",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Вот сейчас я тебя совсем не понимаю."
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "9a4c1ba3-262e-4604-bc50-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: А как к Вам json прилетает на сервер? POST? То есть Вы вообще не можете все данные получить или распарсить не получается?

Comment: Я вообще не могу получить данные. Или может как то не правильно пытаюсь их получить.

Comment: Тогда нужен пример кода, в котором пытаетесь получить сообщение от сервера.

Comment: Пытался по разному:
1) $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST';
2) file_get_contents("php://input");
3) $json = json_decode($_POST['jsondata'], true);
id текстового инпута 'test-client-query-input'

И через curl тоже пробовал, все никак не получается
Изначально я сделал форму отправки у себя и все работало без проблем (искало совпадения по моей базе и в случае, если пусто, посылало запрос на сервис бота).

Comment: По моему проще проверить по логам сервера, были ли обращения к нему, но тут я точно не помощник. Обычно там пишется каким образом, POST или GET было обращение.

Comment: Вам нужно разобратся что когда вызывается, например - как вы могли с помощью curl получить POST c хука? Сам хук вызывает некий скрипт на вашем сервере, конечно если может получить к нему доступ. Для начала попробуйте сами выслать на свой же скрипт POST запрос, и понять работает он или нет, если да, то просто логируйте уже все что зайдет без всяких условий, напримр просто запишите POST в файл при обращении к скрипту.

Comment: И наверное все же ждать - `$update_response = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил спустя энное кол-во времени. Так как сервис просто ссылается как на обработчик то достаточно было :

```
$responseJson_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$response = json_decode($responseJson_str, true);
```

Всем спасибо! Теперь все должно пойти как по маслу!